# How to check if a specific slot has loaded or not using Google Doubleclick API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-dfp

Does anyone know if it's possible to use one of the GPT API functions to check if a specific slot has loaded or not? I would like to add a `slot_loaded` CSS class to the iframe or tag div if possible.

I have taken a look at the `addEventListener` code but I'm not sure how I can use it to work with just one slot as per [docs page](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the event is fired for for 'any' slot on the page, you could check the values for each call to `addEventListener`, and interrogate the `event.slot` property. You'll need to test against a value that is available either globally or hard-coded.

Here is a code example from Google:

```
var targetSlot = googletag.defineSlot(...);
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
    if (event.slot === targetSlot) {
      // Slot specific logic
    }
});'
```

See: [GPT Reference](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference).

Comment: Also there is now an `event.isEmpty` to let you know if an ad was actually served in the slot.  `if (event.slot === targetSlot && !event.isEmpty) {` Which might be useful to someone.

Comment: Shanimal - thats really useful for new code - up till now I've had to check the innerHTML. Thanks!